# Get a single private queue by name in powershell

Tags: powershell, msmq

I want to set permissions for one specific private message queue. I've found [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/915127/419956), but it is a much larger script that deletes queues first if they exist and then (re)creates them. That solution gets references to queues in one of two ways:

1. Via `[System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Create(".\private$\somequeue")`; or
2. By looping through `[System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(".")`.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
GetPrivateQueueByName(".\private$\somequeue")  # Method doesn't exist!
```

But I have not found such a method. I've cycled through all `Get*` methods in the `MessageQueue` namespace.

**Is there a way to get a single private queue by its name**, or otherwise set permissions, without having to iterate all queues and/or recreate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow you to add permissions to your queue:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | Out-Null
(New-Object -TypeName "System.Messaging.MessageQueue" -ArgumentList $queue).SetPermissions(agrs here)
```

Where `$queue` is the queue address, e.g. `".\private$\MyQueue"`.

This uses [SetPermissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.setpermissions(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `MessageQueue`.