# Using powershell to create a create and set security via powershell

Tags: powershell, message-queue, msmq

I am trying to automate the creation of MSMQ queues using powershell

I have no problems creating the queue, I just cannot appear to be able to set the permissions correctly

I have been following what is documented here
[Setting permissions on a MSMQ queue in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765954/setting-permissions-on-a-msmq-queue-in-a-script)

and here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msmq/set-msmqqueueacl?view=win10-ps

This is my command to create the queue

```
New-MsmqQueue -Name "ThisIsTestName" -QueueType Private
```

but when I try to set the permissions, using this command

```
Get-MsmqQueue -Name "ThisIsATestName" -QueueType Private | Set-MsmqQueueAcl -UserName "Everyone" -Allow Peek,Receive,Send,Delete,GetProperties,GetPermissions﻿
```

I am getting this error

```
Set-MsmqQueueACL : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Nullable`1[Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.MessageQueueAccessRights]' required by parameter 'Allow'.
Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:105
+ ... veryone" -Allow Peek,Receive,Send,Delete,GetProperties,GetPermissions
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MsmqQueueACL], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.SetMSMQQueueACLComm
```

So I tried removing all the allow, and just using FullAccess.

This did not give me an error, but it did not set the permissions

looking further, I came across this post:

[Set-MsmqQueueACL - Allow - can't use list as per docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596766/set-msmqqueueacl-allow-cant-use-list-as-per-docs)

So I updated to the following

```
$allows = [Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.MessageQueueAccessRights]::Peek -bor
 [Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.MessageQueueAccessRights]::Receive -bor
 [Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.MessageQueueAccessRights]::Send -bor
 [Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.MessageQueueAccessRights]::Delete -bor
 [Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.MessageQueueAccessRights]::GetPermissions -bor
 [Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.MessageQueueAccessRights]::GetProperties
 Get-MsmqQueue -Name "ThisIsATestName" -QueueType Private | Set-MsmqQueueAcl -UserName "Everyone" -Allow $allows
```

But I am still getting the same error

I know I have made a stupid mistake somewhere but I cannot see what I have done wrong

Attempting to do this on a windows 10 machine

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$var = "PeekMessage,ReceiveMessage,DeleteMessage"
Get-MsmqQueue -Name "testqueue3" -QueueType Private | Set-MsmqQueueAcl -UserName "Everyone" -Allow $var
```

OR

```
Get-MsmqQueue -Name "testqueue3" -QueueType Private | Set-MsmqQueueAcl -UserName "Everyone" -Allow FullControl
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, IAW the MS docs, your command is correct, with one exception, the way the target to receive the permissions is defined. Maybe try using 'Domain Users'

> [Description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msmq/set-msmqqueueacl?view=win10-ps)
>
> The Set-MsmqQueueACL cmdlet modifies the access rights of queues. This
>   cmdlet returns the updated MsmqQueueAcl object. The cmdlet modifies
>   private, public, journal, system journal, system dead-letter, and
>   system transactional dead-letter queues.
>
> Example 1: Modify the ACLs of queues specified by name PowerShell

```
Get-MsmqQueue -Name "Order*" -QueueType Private | Set-MsmqQueueAcl -UserName "CONTOSO\DavidChew" -Allow Delete,Peek,Receive,Send -Deny TakeOwnership
```

> This command gets all the private queues that have names that start
>   with the string Order by using the Get-MsmqQueue cmdlet. The command
>   passes the results to the current cmdlet by using the pipeline
>   operator. The current cmdlet modifies the ACL of the queues.

It also, might be the cmdlets expects a real username as per the MS Docs example. So, then you end up needing a ForEach to get them all. I don't have MSMQ in place so, cannot physically validate.